# How do I get the index of an Item in a LinkedHashMap in a List?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have this Map

```
Map<String, List<OrderLine>> productsNeeded = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

and I want to search in the List(s) for an Item, and then get the Key of the List where the Item was found.

Comment: Do you want to get the key or the index? If you want the key, this is a poor use of a map and you might be better off with a BiMap.

Comment: You should really use a Map<OrderLine, String> instead of your map: a Map is used to find values by key, not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 productsNeeded.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue()
    .contains(matchingElement))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .findFirst();
```

Provided that `matchingElement` is the object of type `OrderLine` you're looking for. Here you're getting `Optional`. To get value you can call `get` or `orElse` to provide a default one, for example:

```
 productsNeeded.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue()
    .contains(matchingElement))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Streams` in Java 8+. I simplified this by making the inner key a `List<String>`:

```
String item = "";
Map<String, List<String>> productsNeeded = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String key = productsNeeded.entrySet().stream()
                           .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(item::equals))
                            //Or e -> e.getValue().contains(item)
                           .map(Entry::getKey)
                           .findFirst()
                           .orElse("");
```

Where you can put something else in the default value of `orElse`.